# Code Igniter - creating folder in FTP

Tags: codeigniter, ftp, mkdir

I need your help. I am trying to create folders on my FTP server through my Code Igniter web application. If the manager clicks attachments on projects a folder gets created if it doesn't exists yet and then through file upload he populates it with files.

I have achieved all this when running the code on localhost (the folders got created, and file upload worked too), however when I uploaded my app to a live site I couldn't create folders, so I googled a little and found out I should use the ftp library, because I couldn't create the folders with the relative paths I had.

However, I still cant seem to create the folder with the following code.

```
if($this->ftp->list_files('attachments/výkres'.$id) == FALSE) 
{
    $this->ftp->mkdir('attachments/'.$id);
}
```

I always get the error:

> Unable to create the directory you have specified.

Comment: try providing full path start with public_html < $this->ftp->mkdir('/public_html/foo/bar/', 0755); > also set permission

Comment: don't forget to add slashes at start and end   $this->ftp->mkdir('/attachments/'.$id.'/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you :

use with `full path` with **starting** and **ending** `slashes` like this:

```
if($this->ftp->list_files('/public_html/your_path/attachments/yýkres'.$id.'/') == FALSE) 
{
    $this->ftp->mkdir('/public_html/your_path/attachments/'.$id.'/', DIR_WRITE_MODE);
}
```

for more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/ftp.html#CI_FTP::mkdir